# The meaning of “how her foot feels rooted”

Tags: sentence-meaning

My question is, what is the meaning of the sentence? “How her foot feels rooted now as if it is really”.

The person is talking about the right foot of Venus (The Birth of Venus).

> **Sandro** Leo can I ask you something?
>
> *Leonardo nods*
>
> **Sandro** How did you do this?
>
> *Pause*
>
> I mean this – (*Imitating the pose of Venus's right foot*)
> How her foot feels rooted now as if it is really –
> (*Gestures.*) The shading here. (*Points.*)

From *Botticelli in the Fire*, by Jordan Tannahill.

Comment: I know the word “rooted”, but probably do not understand the context. Here it is. “How did you do this? I mean this(imitating the pose of Venus’s right foot) How her foot feels rooted now as if it is really- The shading here. The source is Botticelli in the Fire drama)

Comment: It's her left foot, not her right foot, that appears rooted. She's facing the viewer so her left foot from her own perspective is on the right from the viewer's perspective.

Comment: Oh, Ok. So it means she is stable and connected with everything perfectly, aware of her origin and ready for the life on the land. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure if the cited utterance is faithfully transcribed. I can *just about* parse it as being structurally similar to *How he laughed! As if he was really amused* (although he *wasn't* amused). But I can't impose that parsing without some help from the punctuation. And even if I *could*, it makes no sense in relation to the foot of a statue or other representation of Venus (assuming that *is* the context here).

Comment: Another character is asking later in the text: “Is there something odd about the angle of her foot, What do you think?” So I was wondering What is so strange about her foot? Because I am also not sure if they are talking about Venus’s right foot from her point of view or from the viewer’s point of view (the right side of the painting, the leg on which she is standing)

Comment: Since Venus's left, "rooted foot" is not really doing anything, "the pose" must refer to the position of her right, "unrooted" foot.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Why are you answering in comments?

Comment: @tchrist — I don't think that's an answer — I'm just confirming that when they say "right foot," they are talking about her right foot as from her point of view.

Answer (score 1):

## WYSIWYG

**No!**

It does not mean something "metaphorical" and "abstract". It means precisely what it says. Look at the picture of her left foot:

[image: bottom of Venus's left foot]

See the lines suggesting roots? See the lines of shading? See how all the lines look like a great big giant crown of tree roots bearing her weight through the angle of her left foot at the very same angle as she’s leaning?

That's all it means. Anything in the way of literary interpretation beyond that is off-topic on this site. You would need to [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com) for non-language things like that, not here.

Comment: "*See how all the lines look like a great big giant crown of tree roots bearing her weight through the angle of her left foot at the very same angle as she’s leaning?*" You mean the lines you drew over the original? :D But yes, this seems very much like the intended meaning.